# I try to go to my phpmyadmin localhost but MySQL said: Documentation Cannot connect: invalid settings

Tags: xampp, localhost

[image]

MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.

Comment: Did you have any issues when you installed XAMPP?

Comment: no error came  issue when i install XAMPP .

Comment: /* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
                                       $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3306';

Comment: problem solved  /* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write instead of `localhost` `127.0.0.1`

or

Open `config.inc.php` and find `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';` and change `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`. It should work, it worked by me.

Answer (score 1):

change "config.inc.php " file

3306 is mysql main port

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3306';

Answer (score 0):

i tried to acess my website through localhost and i got a message said that The webpage cannot be found HTTP 404 Most likely causes: •There might be a typing error in the address. •If you clicked on a link, it may be out of date. What you can try: Retype the address. Go

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).